# UTF-8 format corrupted after building jar file

Tags: java, netbeans, printing, utf-8, jar

I'm trying to send arabic letters to my printer with UTF-8 format and it works while I'm running the program from the green run symbol in the netbeans, but after I clean and build the project and run the file from the generated jar file, the printer prints a bunch of question marks instead of arabic letters, any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a Locale related problem.

1. have a look at [Understanding Locale in the Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/locale-140624.html)
2. check which Locale is used when you run it inside Netbeans, something like  `System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());`
3. after you got this information run your application `java -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=GB your.jar` to check if this solves your problem

   4. amend your code to use this as your default Locale, see [Using a Default Locale](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/locale-140624.html#using)